# Sending HTML file with Images through email IOS

Tags: c#, html, ios, xamarin.ios

This is more of a general question about whether or not its actually possible to achieve what I want.

The basis is that my app allows the user to fill out various tables of data for a preventative maintenance check sheet. They can also attach images to this sheet which saves to the temporary storage on the IOS app. Once its complete they then press a button which generates a HTML document through a StreamWriter. Through this StreamWriter I have created, the images are also appended through URL references to the images in the temporary folder.

The HTML file (Generated Form) is then presented to the user using a WebView. Once the user has checked all the information, they then press a button which presents a MailViewController.

The HTML file (Generated Form) is then automatically attached and once the email has been entered you press send and everything works as it should.

The problem I am now having is that im not sure if its possible to keep the images in the html document. Once you open the HTML file on the receiving device, the images no longer loads because they no longer exist according to the HTML file.

So basically is it possible to keep the images in the HTML file once opened on the receiving device.

Sorry for the long description but its needed so you get an understanding of what I am actually doing. All the code I have written works as it should but just wanted to know if this is possible or not.

Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use base 64 encoded strings for the images and it should work. Since the images would be passed along with the html

Comment: Would you do this at the time of creating the HTML in the streamwriter? Also, would this slow the application down a lot?

Comment: No it won’t slow the application down at all. Usually you would do it at the point of the user selecting the image or capturing the image.

Comment: Ok I will try this tomorrow thank you! If I still wanted to store the image and them do it in the streamwriter, would this affect much or would this be ok. Only reason being I have implemented a lot fo code which does the work of saving the image etc :)

Comment: You can convert an already saved image then replace the src for the images you converted to be the data url. You can do this in JavaScript since you are using a web view.

Comment: Ok will try this and let you know how it goes. Will try Javascript if its more efficient but might take me a while as my skills on javascript are very minimal